# EVEmodel:fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc

I am on a linux based server trying to run EVE for the phylogenetic ANOVA. It appears I need gsl when I run the compiling code. So I downloaded gsl-2.6 and put it into the same working directory, I still get the same Error:
Inital Command:

```
gcc EVEmodel.c -o EVEmodel -O3 probabilityfunctions.c treefunctions.c regimefunctions.c myio.c mystat.c bfgs.c -D GSL_RANGE_CHECK_OFF -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Followed by the error, which initially led me to download gsl:

```
EVEmodel.c:8:26: fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
probabilityfunctions.c:6:26: fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from treefunctions.c:11:0:
myio.h:2:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
regimefunctions.c:4:26: fatal error: gsl/gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
myio.c:2:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from mystat.c:8:0:
myio.h:2:28: fatal error: gsl/gsl_matrix.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Is the "linux based server" actually running Ubuntu? Do you have administrative privileges on it (i.e. can you install software with `apt`)?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.

Comment: Generally, you need to do more than download packages like gsl and put them into a local directory - they need to be built and installed, into a system-wide location such as `/usr/local` if you have sufficient privileges otherwise into your home directory. In the latter case the main software that you are trying to build needs to be configured to locate them.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install corresponding header files [from deb-packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gsl%2Fgsl_matrix.h):

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl-dev
```

and then retry the compilation. Or use `-L` and `-I` flags (see `man gcc` or [online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/gcc.1.html)) for local GSL library.